Docker and Podman show the same containers and images
How is it possible that docker ps shows the same containers as podman ps?
I don't know exactly since when, but Docker and Podman seem to have "merged" together.
I'm saying this because when I run docker ps it shows me the containers created with Podman, even the pod.
I can also delete, with docker, containers created with podman and viceversa.
I already checked that there was no alias overwriting the docker command.
$> type docker
docker is hashed (/usr/bin/docker)

$> docker -v
Docker version 27.3.1, build ce12230

$> podman -v
podman version 5.0.3

Also, the commands docker|podman volume ls and docker|podman images show the same results.

The env var DOCKER_HOST is set to unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock.
Unsetting the variable worked, but only on the current shell, so it's a temporary solution.
I searched my bashrc and that variable is not set inside it, where could it be set?

The command podman-docker is not installed on my system.

Do you have a $DOCKER_HOST environment variable set?  Docker has two parts, the CLI tool and a system-level daemon, and if you're talking to the same daemon then you'll see the same content regardless of which CLI tool you use with it.

Also take a look at the output of docker context ls; this is effectively a way of persistently switching between different DOCKER_HOST values. On my local system, I have contexts defined that let the docker cli connect to both my user and root podman instances.

The CLI client doesn't run containers or store images. Show the engine details with docker version; docker info. Podman is also well known for impersonating docker.

Thank you guys for your help, I'm going to update the question with new information.

You may have installed podman-docker. This package installs a script named docker that emulates the Docker CLI with podman.
Uninstall it and you should be back to normal: apt remove podman-docker

@micke sorry for the delay. I checked and I don't have podman-docker installed.

In the end, I put this line of code unset DOCKER_HOST in my bashrc.
But I do not think it's the right solution, thus I'm not going to accept this answer as the correct one.
